# Cannot read property of undefined error Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined, instagram

Getting an error when trying to retrieve the amount of people someone is followed_by on Instagram.

The API is getting called properly but in line 10 I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'followed_by' of undefined".

Code is below.

```
function hello() {
        var $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/7624/?access_token={access-token}&count=100';
        var $access_token = "257177111.ca91fd6.d912fbc4875d4d81abe28ee7b436d8da";
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: $url,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp : "callback",
                success: function(data) {
                         alert(data.counts.followed_by);
                    },
                error: function(data, error) {
                            alert("bad");       
                        }
            });
    }
```

Comment: You should examine the contents of `data` before accessing it, because it seems that `data.counts` is undefined, so you of course can't get the `follow_by` property. Either because `counts` isn't the property name, or the response is empty or something

Comment: Counts is the property name though. Am I making my call incorrect?

Comment: Do this in your ajax call: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); },`. Then you can go into the console and examine what `data` is actually giving you.

Comment: @tb11 Data is logging everything I need. Username, website, etc. However when I try doing data.username or something of that sort, it comes back undefined.

Comment: @AGLearner JavaScript is case-sensitive...is it `Counts` or `counts`. You should post the structure of `data`

Comment: @Ian here is a picture of the data: http://cl.ly/image/3P2m1L15132Z

Comment: @AGLearner Unless I'm mistaken, that shows that the object in the variable `data` contains two keys - `data` and `meta`. That means you need to use `data.data.counts.followed_by`. I *think*

Comment: @Ian you are correct Ian. If you want post this as an answer and I will 1 up this. It is good to know that data and meta can make a difference in your calls. I had no idea.

Comment: @HAHAHAAHAHPROGRAMMING I added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
alert(data.counts.followed_by);
```

to

```
alert(data);
alert(data.counts);
alert(data.counts.followed_by);
```

The first one that comes up as undefined is the one that doesn't exist & then fix your problem from there.

If is a whole lot easier to use console.log() to find these sorts of problems because you can just do `console.log(data)` & it gives you the whole object which you can inspect using any of the available dev tools used for that.

Comment: I am still getting undefined. I added your 3 lines of code after success.